# how to change template field in mvc form to radio button?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

When I use ASP.NET MVC to build a registration form, I use a field for sex.

```
<div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.sex)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.sex)
    </div>
```

I want to change text box to radio button to act as male and female.

Comment: Can you add the code for your model class? What is the type of the `sex` property?

Answer (score 0):

If model.sex is a specific type (SexType) then you can use a custom editor:

http://www.growingwiththeweb.com/2012/12/aspnet-mvc-display-and-editor-templates.html

if it's just a string field or boolean, then you can create your own:

```
<div class="editor-field">
<input type="radio" name="@Html.NameFor(model=>model.sex)" value="Male" @(model.sex=="Male"?"checked":"")>Male
<br/>
<input type="radio" name="@Html.NameFor(model=>model.sex)" value="Female" @(model.sex=="Female"?"checked":"")>Female
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.sex)
</div>
```

Comment: Or more simply `@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.sex, "Male", new { id = "male" }) @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.sex, "Female", new { id = "female" })`